# 'Handle' on rear guard of fan

Tags: fans

I just bought an oscillating standing electric fan, and I have noticed a little wire 'handle' thing on the rear wire mesh guard. Can anyone tell me what it is for? I wondered whether it was to aid changing the direction it was pointing in, when not in oscillating mode, but grasping the motor housing is very easy.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, it's a handle for lifting. It *could* be used as a bracket to hang the fan onto a hook - but better make sure the oscillating switch is off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did wonder about that, but it looks kind of puny for the weight of the thing. The picture in my post is of a desk fan, and the feature in question is at the top (at twelve o'clock), but on mine, which is on a floor stand, it is at nine o'clock, and there are lugs when fitting the guard to the motor so I haven't put in on a quarter circle displaced. I guess the maker will use the same fan guards for both types.

Comment: You can leave the oscillating function on, just be prepared for the "thump thump" of the rest of the fan banging against the wall. :)

Comment: It should be movable, just release the clips and turn round. Obviously the weight of any fan will dictate whether it's a good idea to hang or not.

Comment: It's got a little hole in the rim, with nut and bolt, which, if fitted as per the instructions, mean you can't rotate the guard.

Comment: To clarify, the back half of the guard is in a fixed position, determined by two protruding lugs on the motor housing, which engage in holes in the rear guard at 12  and six o'clock only. Then the front half is attached, and the instructions specify that it is fixed in position using a single nut & bolt through holes in the rim.

Comment: Plus the clips of course.

Comment: Of course, the ruddy gert motor sticking out the back of the fan housing, plus having to keep it wired to the stand, would probably put paid to any idea of hanging it. ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - not unknown to have it hanging on a bracket sticking out from the wall, when there's no room left on the desk it's intended for! Maybe better than the floor. Last night's gig had mine on top of the amp on top of the speaker. Could maybe have put it *in front* to give a Leslie sound?